# Accessing Google Analytics data from within site

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm looking to pass the current traffic source/medium through a contact form on a site (hidden field). I know that GA is tracking the data, and I wasn't sure if there was a method to get data from the current session from any of the ga javascript objects.

The idea is that if I can get easy access to it, I can just put it straight into the form to track it from my own backend. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics uses cookies for tracking data -- see http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html for names & descriptions of cookies used.

The `__utmz` cookie contains source/campaign/medium data -- http://www.randycullom.com/chatterbox/archives/2008/10/google_analytic.html has a good breakdown of the data inside the Google Analytics cookies..